# How to display Multi Checkbos select Custom Field on the post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

i have create a Custom Post Type calle "Places".
I have created a Custom Field with

Field Type "Multi CheckBox"
Option Title "Type of Pub"
Option values "Sports, Rock, Biker, Beer, Live Band, Restro, Gastro, Irish, Karaoke Bar"
Field Title "Type of Pub"
Field name "typeofpub"

When i Add New Places, Type of Pub with Values with checkbox shows up on edit page.
I selected all the values (Sports, Rock......)

How do i call the metadata to display is custom field on a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loop:

```
echo implode (', ', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'typeofpub', true) ? : array() );
```

This will print all 'typeofpub' comma separed.

If you want to do something more advanced wheen you print, e.g. wrap it in some html, a good way is create your own function in functions.php, something lie:

```
function typeofpub( $post_id = 0 ) {
  if ( empty( $post_id ) ) {
    global $post;
    $post_id = isset( $post->ID ) ? $post->ID : 0;
  }
  if ( empty( $post_id )  ) return;
  $types = (array) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'typeofpub', true);
  if ( ! empty($types) ) {
    echo '<ul class="types_container">';
    foreach( $types as $type) {
      echo '<li class="type-' . sanitize_title_with_dashes($type) . '">';
      echo ucwords($type);
      echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

Then in the loop simply use it in like so: `typeofpub();`

You can change the html output as you want, in my example an unordered list is printed, where the `ul` tag has the class `types_container` and every `li` item has the class `type-{$type}` e.g. for the type 'Sport' is outputted something like:

```
<li class="type-sport">Sport</li>
```

The function can be used also outside the loop, passing a post id as param, e.g.

```
typeofpub( 10 );
```

Comment: thanks it worked. but i have one question. i will have similar values for ton of other posts like for eg. typeofpub : sports will be for think 100 places.My main intention is to make these values clickable , when someone clicks sports , it should show all the posts from custom post type places related to type of pub: sports.

Comment: And can i add a class to each value , so that i can attach an icon with each value. For Eg: Sports Icon then SPORTS, Rock Icon then ROCK

Comment: The 1st comment is another question. Search for them here and if you don't find anything ask a new question. For 2nd comment I'me adding more info on my answer. @luckyrajiv

Comment: So, shall i add the above function in fucntions.php, then in single-places.php i should call <?php typeofpub() ?> instead of  <p>Type of Pub : <?php echo implode (', ', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'typeofpub', true) ? : array() ); ?></p>
please help i am not sure if i understood

Comment: `<p>Type of Pub:</p><?php typeofpub(); ?>` in `single-places.php`. @luckyrajiv

Comment: thanks that worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Now i want them to clickable links like tags. if i click on sports, it should show all the posts from particular post type in archive form

Comment: @luckyrajiv as said before, this is another question, please search the site for an existing question/answer and if you don't find anything ask new question.

Comment: i have asked new a question, please see if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `get_metadata()` or `get_post_custom()`function. In you are inside the loop in your a theme file you can use, for example:

```
$post_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);

if(isset($post_meta['typeofpub'])) echo $post_meta['typeofpub'];
```

If the field allow multple selections you need to loop or implode the results as @G.M. suggests in his/her answer. For example:

```
$post_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);

if(isset($post_meta['typeofpub']) && is_array($post_meta['typeofpub'])) {
    echo implode(' - ', $post_meta['typeofpub']);
}
```

Comment: And if i have to call just single value custom field like:        Address: Chicago, USA

Comment: If your field allow multiple selection the value is stored as arrays, even if there is a single value. But ask G.M, you have accept his answer, not mine so ask him ;) (just joking)

Comment: i mean how can i call a single custom field

Comment: In the code above a **single custom field** is called. But if it allow multiple selections, it will have several values stored under the same single field. Maybe if you post the code of the checkboxes I can give you a more accurate aswer.

Comment: Checkboxes thing is working. if i have custom field called address. How do i call that in single-places.php

Comment: I didn't say that checkboxes are not working, I ask for the code to see the way the work and the possible data format. I think you don't understand the concept of how you can have **one single field** storing multiple values in array format. I like questioner learn with the questions, not only getting a ready-to-use code without learning.

Comment: i am sorry, i am not perfect in wordpress coding. i am learning. thats why i ask so many questions. Apologies, if i hurt any feelings.

Comment: You have not hurt anything, why do you think so? Keep asking and learnig.

Comment: thank you. can you check this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113194/convert-custom-fields-option-values-to-tags-taxonomy