# convert Custom Fields Option-Values to Tags/Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have Custom Post Type "Places". In that I have Created Custom Fields. Like:

**Option Title »** Type of Pub
**Option values »** Sports, Rock, Biker, Beer, Live Band, Restro, Gastro, Irish, Karaoke Bar
**Field Title »** Type of Pub
**Field name »** typeofpub

What I want is to convert each title and values to tags. So that I should be able to click on them. And when I click on them it should go to the `archive-tags.php` and display all the posts with that option value.

Comment: If you want using taxonomy terms, why don't use terms instead of using custom fields and then convert to terms?

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: I mean register a custom taxonomy and use that instead of custom fileds. If you want to know ho register a custom taxonomy you need the function [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

Comment: @G.M. Could change things to know if the OP is going to prevent that users can insert any of the terms "invalid"? I mean, with a metabox I could use default values ​​of the checkboxes to select which terms will become tags.

Comment: @iEmanuele in that case is possible register a taxonomy with `show_ui = false` and create a metabox to let users select 'valid' terms (so terms created by admin). Only reason to implement this custom fields to terms conversion is if there are a lot of existing posts with already assigned fields and re-assign to taxonomy terms would be difficult. My first question to OP is for that reason. If he had aswered me _"because I have a lot of posts with already assigned custom fields"_ probably I started an answer...

Comment: Hi, i created custom taxonomy called 'Music' for custom post type called 'Places' Now how can i display the custom taxonomy in the single-places.php

Comment: @luckyrajiv `get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'Places', 'Places: ', ', ', '' );` see [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)